# Logic before "dispatch"-event

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I want to do some logic before MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, but MvcEvent::getTarget() function returns object of Mvc\Application instead of Controller if I set priority above 1 like:

```
$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'routing'), 100);
```

If I set priority to negative value, I get the Controller object, but it's fired after action-function. How can I get the Controller object in this case?

Comment: The dispatch stage is where the controller is created and the action is called on it. If you do something before it then there is no controller ... you do something after it's already done.

Answer (score 0):

```
// in your Module
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()
      ->getEventManager()
      ->getSharedManager()
      ->attach(
            'Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface', 
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'), 
            2
        );
}

public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $a)
{
    $target = $a->getTarget();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `MvcEvent::getRouteMatch()` to determine what controller will be dispatched (if any), or attach to the controller event manager inside the controller itself by overriding `AbstractActionController:setEventManager()`.

ie:

```
// in your controller

public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
{
    parent::setEventManager($events);

    $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'preDispatch'), 100);
}

public function preDispatch(MvcEvent $event)
{
    // your custom logic here
}
```